# Uhuru USB microphone is detected, but no sound is picked up

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have Ubuntu 20.10 on my aging desktop, and an Uhuru UM-925 USB microphone.

When I plug it in, it is properly detected and selected as the primary input device. `pavucontrol` confirms the device is selected.

In `alsamixer`, there are several input sliders for the built-in analog 1/8" pins, but if I switch sound cards to the USB microphone one, it shows a single slider at 0. If I increase that bar, I instead pick up static at the selected volume.

Unfortunately due to COVID restrictions, it's hard to test either this microphone on another device, or other USB microphones with this one.

Here is a screenshot of my sound settings:

[image: screenshot of my Sound settings in Ubuntu]